# UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) return null

Tags: django

I'm trying to upload files using django and I wrote the following codes:

```
from django import forms
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()

def uploadexcel(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print(form)
    print(form.is_valid())
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("success")    
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render(request,'index.html', {'form': form})
```

I can get the value of **request.POST** and **request.FILES**.
I use form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) to build **form**
but the value of **form** is null

Comment: What do you mean, the value is null? Where are you setting that? Python does not use "null" as a value.

Comment: can you show the form in your template please?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your form like this.

```
form = UploadFileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the problem lies here

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
>   was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute
>   enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Read the docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/